# Is there a way to remove non unique rows in data frame without using apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame with over a million rows where I would like to drop any row that does not contain all unique values within the row itself.

```
    0   1   2   4   3
0   13  3   2   0   3 # Want to drop 
1   13  72  2   13  1 # Want to drop
2   13  3   2   8   5
```

Is there a faster way of achieving the same result as the code below?

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.is_unique, axis=1)]
#     0  1  2  4  3
# 2  13  3  2  8  5
```

Comment: I think that's the fastest method for your use case. You could use `df[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(df.shape[1])]`, but I doubt it will be faster.

Comment: there are ways without using apply, but not faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Numpy* is known to operate significantly faster than *Pandas*.

So attempt the following code:

```
nCol = df.shape[1]
df[np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: np.unique(row).size == nCol, 1, df.values)]
```

My comparison of execution time, using *%timeit*, indicates that my code
is about 3 times faster than yours.

For bigger source DataFrame this difference can be greater.
Check on your own and than pass the result in a comment.

By the way: I checked also solution proposed by *enke*, but it seems
to be slower than your code.

Comment: This is much faster, with the original solution `12.2 s ± 46.8 ms per loop` with the numpy solution here `3.8 s ± 17.2 ms per loop`